# Terminal lines intermittently invisible or corrupt on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, display-driver, nvidia-graphics-card

I am running gnome-terminal under Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a weird problem that I haven't managed to find any info on. Whenever I type a command, the resulting output is frequently - but not always - invisible until the screen gets refreshed from e.g. scrolling the window, me pressing enter until the terminal content starts scrolling off screen, me marking some lines of text or similar.

Also, pressing `CTRL-L` also doesn't behave correctly. Usually, the first time I press it, the cursor goes to the top, but the window content remains either unchanged and if I start typing I will overwrite previous lines, OR content that was previously hidden as described above becomes visible. Pressing `CTRL-L` again clears the window correctly.

Usually, entire lines are missing, but from time to time I also see partly corrupted lines.

The problem *might* be more frequent whenever colored output is shown (as from e.g. `git status`) but I can't say for sure.

As you can imagine this drives me completely insane, but to my surprise I wasn't able to find any info on any similar topic. Has anyone seen this problem? Is it likely to be a problem with my config, my window manager, my OS or my graphics driver? I don't have any graphics related problems with any other programs.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Intel Xeon W360 @ 3.33GHz with the following video config:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

PCI (sysfs)  
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GT216GL [Quadro 400]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:69 memory:ea000000-eaffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:eb080000-eb0fffff
```